# Bezier Curves With Java Robot Class

Tags: java, mouse, bezier, awtrobot

I'm working on a universal robot, capable of performing day to day tasks that a human would normally do.

One of the classes is 'mouse', which handles all mouse related commands such as movement, pressing buttons, so on and so forth.

I've read a lot about Bezier Splines (Bezier Curves), however I just don't understand it.

From what I've read, I need 4 control points.

```
Point0 = Start X
Point1 = Unknown
Point2 = Unknown
Point3 = End X
```

How do I find the unknown coordinates so my mouse movement will be a smooth curve?

I greatly appreciate your time and I look forward for a response.

Comment: if it is about moving from the current location to the desired button, why not just use a line?

Comment: Hello Randy, I'm in need of realistic movement. Moving on the dot is simply too robotic.

Answer (score 2):

*Any* two control points would give a smooth Bézier curve, by definition, and a straight line between the start and end points would also be a smooth curve. You might actually be asking one or both of two questions:

1) *Given a path I want the mouse to follow, how do I compute points along the path?* You need a parametric equation for the path. A parametric equation for points along a straight line segment `PQ` is

```
r(t) = P + tPQ
```

where `P` is the start point, `PQ` is the vector form of the line segment, and `t` varies from 0 to 1.

2) *How do I find Bézier control points such that my mouse follows a "natural" path?* This one is very subjective; there's no right answer, because as I said, *any* two control points will yield a continuous path. You might simply choose control points 1/3 and 2/3 along the path, perturbed by, say, 5% of their coordinates. Then you'd use the parametric Bézier equation to compute the points along the curve. Fiddle with that 5% figure to get something that pleases you.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. 

Do you think you have time to write up a small example?

I've been researching this for hours upon hours, and I'm ready to pull my hair out, heh.

Comment: Small example of which, now? You didn't tell me which question you're really asking.

Comment: Sorry, essentially I want to take two points, A, and B, start, and end, generate the control points and turn the straight path into a curve such as: 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/Bezier_700.gif

Answer (score 1):

hi you better sample the curve from more than one 4-point bezier.
to smoothly join two 4-point beziers you need to do this:

Bezier1(a0,a1,a2,a3) ... a0..a3  are point coordinates (as vectors) of previous curve

Bezier2(b0,b1,b2,b3) ... b0..b3  are point coordinates (as vectors) of this curve

b0 = a3              ... to ensure continuity c0

b1 = b0+(a3-a2)      ... to ensure continuity c1

b2 = unknown

b3 = position of mouse

for the first curve you can set a0,a1=mouse position

all b3 points are mouse position

all b2 points are mouse position distorted by some scale ... if you use no scale its also ok ...

when you draw with mouse you can add next bezier curve after some constant length is moved from the start

if you need more exact aproximation of mouse path so lower the length constant for curve segment. If it is not enough then you must use conversion of 4 point interpolation to 4 point bezier which is not as simple.

if you are not limited by bezier use interpolation instead, then all points are mouse position ...

hope it helps